# Broken link additional images after moving server

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Recently we moved the website of our client to a new server, and in doing so the links to almost all the images were broken. I've been able to fix the majority of them, but somehow in the woocommerce, it's not showing additional images.

At first it wasn't even showing the primary image, but I was able to solve that by fixing the links in the database.
The aditional images however are still not loading. Using a product feed plugin I've found that they are trying to load from a broken url (as is shown in the attached image).

Now, I'm unable to find where the path for the additional images is in order to change it. I've searched the database for any '//wp_content/' links but nothing shows.

How do I go about fixing this?

[image: Example of product feed]

Comment: how did you perform the migration? If you have WooCommerce specific questions you need to ask those in a WooCommerce community or via their support, 3rd party plugin user/dev support questions are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: I performed the migration using a tool that my hosting service provides. My hosting service is Webempresa.

Comment: have you contacted them? It's difficult to debug what happened if it was done using a closed source proprietary tool